# $\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(\log x)^r} \ dx$ converges for $r>1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, proof-verification

I need to prove that

$$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(\log x)^r} \ dx$$

converges for $r>1$ and diverges for $r\le 1$.

I tried to do it with comparsion, but since it requires an exact value for $r$, I guess I need to solve this integral. That's what I tried:

$$\frac{1}{x(\log x)^r} = \frac{p(x)}{x} + \frac{q(x)}{\log^rx }$$

then $p(x)\log^r x+xq(x) = 0$ but I can't find $p$ and $q$, so I don't know if this is the best method of integration.

Hmmm, maybe I can see the integral as this:

$$\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\log^r x} \ dx$$

and take $u=\log x \implies du = \frac{1}{x} dx$, therefore we end with:

$$\int_{\log 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^r}du $$

which converges if $r>1$ and diverges for $r\le1$, right?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that works.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x \log^r x}$ is the derivative of $\frac{\log^{1-r}x}{1-r}$ except for $r= 1$ where it is $\log \log x = \lim_{ r \to 1} \frac{\log^{1-r}x}{1-r}$